# Table header is read twice by voice over in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, chromium, voiceover

Voice over reads all table header twice in google chrome on MAC.

Header is read immediately twice and it will be very annoying for a11y users

Comment: I found a workaround to remove aria-label and add role="cell" but this caused issues in mac safari. so looking for a better work around or fixes

Comment: Can you post your code?  You might be trying to "fix" a problem that isn't a problem. How does the table sound in safari and firefox?

Comment: This issue is seen on table in any chromium based browser in chrome.    https://codepen.io/sivachaitanyaa-backflipt-com/pen/bGmpVjm 
  and https://codepen.io/appslogix/pen/AvJBjN is sample codepen with HTML table, even here u can see this issue

Comment: Your first code example has a lot of errors. You should not specify a `role` on a `<table>`. You're using `role="landmark"`, which isn't even a valid role. It's an abstract role. And the scope on the `<th>` should be `col` instead of `column`.

Comment: my bad i forked first one and was experimenting, pls refer second link, its simple table

Comment: This is a chromium bug and is tracked in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1145591&q=voiceover%20table%20header&can=2. thanks for the help